# Issue on finding the multiplicative inverse of matrix using rings (Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Example 9: The set $W$ of all symbols of the form \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are any integers. Addition and multiplication are defined thus:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} a+e&b+f\\c+g&d+h \end{bmatrix}
\text{and} \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ae+bg&af +bh\\ce+ dg&cf+dh\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Show that the element \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix} of the ring $W$ has no multiplicative inverse in $W$.

---

I’ve tried testing if the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$ exists by finding its determinant, however when I found the determinant, it equaled to $3$. I thought that if the determinant is not equal to zero, then the inverse must exist? How can I show that this matrix has no multiplicative inverse in $W$?

Comment: If the determinant is nonzero then the inverse exists over $\mathbb{Q}$; the basic facts of linear algebra work over fields. However in order for the inverse to exist over $\mathbb{Z}$ the determinant has to be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$, meaning $\pm 1$. This is how it works over general commutative rings.

Comment: You ring is defined over matrices in *integers*.

Comment: $MM' = 1\overset{\rm det}{\Longrightarrow}|M||M'| = 1\,\ {\rm in}\,\ \color{#c00}{\Bbb Z}\Longrightarrow |M| = \pm1 \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is specifically defined as being a set of matrices with integer entries. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ is definitely invertible over the space of *real* matrices, but its inverse contains fractions and hence is not part of $W$.

To prove that it's not invertible over $W$, you can use a proof by contradiction - suppose that $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in W$ is the inverse of the given matrix, i.e. $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} = I$. Then you can derive a set of equations for $a, b, c, d$ and then show that there are no integer solutions.